# Why does the CSS min-width attribute not force a div to have the specified minimum width?

Tags: html, css

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            div {
                border:1px solid #000;
                min-width: 50%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>This is some text. </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I believe the div should be 50 percent of the page, unless, for some reason, the text inside the div makes it larger. However, the border around the div stretches across the entire page width. This occurs in both IE and Firefox.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you provide `absolute` positioning to the element, it will be `50%` in Firefox.  However, IE doesn't like the `min-width` or `min-height` attributes, so you will have to define width as `50%` also for it to work in IE.

Comment: The solution for me (a DIV) was min-width with display:table

Answer (score 14):

> I believe the div should be 50 percent of the page, unless, for some reason, the text inside the div makes it larger.

`min-width` does not set a minimum starting width from which your block will grow; rather it limits how far the block can shrink.

In `min-width: 50%;`, the `50%` is in reference to the containing block. I've never used percentages with `min-width`, but I find it can be useful with other units. For example if I have a block (like a column of text) that I want to be full width, but I don't ever want it to go below a minimum width, I could use something like `{width: 100%; min-width: 250px;}`.

Note the caveats on IE support mentioned by others.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for: "I want to be full width, but I don't ever want it to go below a minimum width, I could use something like {width: 100%; min-width: 250px;}."

Answer (score 7):

Without `min-width`, your div will take whole page width, that is how `display:block` elements behave. Adding `min-width` cannot make it smaller.

Changing `display` property to `absolute` or `float` property to `left` will make the element to shrink to fit contents. Then, `min-width` start to make sense.

Comment: +1 and thanks!  "display: table" was just what I needed to fix this issue with a <ul> element that I only wanted to grow.

Answer (score 2):

To add to what [Chris Serra said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198153/why-does-the-css-min-width-attribute-not-force-a-div-to-have-the-specified-mini#198165), in IE < 7 (and in 7? I can't keep track these days, but definitely < 8), `width` behaves exactly like `min-width` is supposed to behave.

Answer (score 2):

You are telling it that the minimum width is 50%. Since there is nothing else taking up the space, it will take all of it (except for margins).

If you give it a max-width of say 75%, firefox should constrain it to that. IE6 will still ignore it.

As David Kolar already said, many of us typically do not use percentages for min-width.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try an IE specific style-sheet and include and expression like:

```
print("width:expression(document.body.clientWidth < 1024? "50%" : "100%");");
```

This will change the width setting based on the width of the browser window at load time. I personally like to use px as the unit measurement, but you need to try it with your specific setup.