# Floated 48% div needs a full line of text to keep it's size?

Tags: html, css

The template to rebuild my website works great except for the 2 divs in the center which are floated left & right. They seem to need at least a full line of text in each one to stay open.

If not the navigation on the left seems to go off screen to the left. The left & right divs are fixed widths.

The 2 center ones are floated I believe properly & cleared. Each 48% width.

Is there a way to keep them fully expanded for pages that do not have a line that covers the full width. I know my screen is 1920px's wide & they are getting wider.

I have been researching this for days & always seem to end up at this site.

The only thing I can think of is to put say 16 - 100px wide spacer gif's side by side in each center 48% div. That just isn't right.

Is there a way to keep the div's full width?

Full page sample. If either of the 2 full lines in the 2 center div's are shortened the left nav goes further left. 
http://www.trurons.com/travel/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198153/why-does-the-css-min-width-attribute-not-force-a-div-to-have-the-specified-minim

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the source of the page you linked and can't figure out what you are talking about and I can't visually grasp it from your question.

If the other posters answer does not help I would reccommend looking at this site here for a refresher of how HTML elements interact with eachother. You probably already know it but the refresher might help you figure out why your elements shrink and expand based on what is around and in them.

http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

Comment: The 2 center div's, if you take out the lines that fill the width and/or wrap. The left navigation starts going left off screen. Is there a way to stop this when using short lines?

Comment: I added a 2nd page that should show the left nav is pushed off screen to the left. Because the long line of text was removed from the left of center div.
http://www.trurons.com/travel/broke.php
Compared to the page with the long line in.
http://www.trurons.com/travel/

Is there a way to keep this from happening? For pages that don't 
have long lines.

Comment: If I absolute position the far left div #left_content that keeps it from moving. Still leaves the original question: As can be seen in http://www.trurons.com/travel/broke.php Is there a way to keep the center 2 div's fully expanded without having text that wraps to keep it open? In broke.php the center right div is moving left because the wrapping line was removed from the center left div.

Comment: I made a jsfiddle that shows my problem. I've learned a lot over the weeks looking for a fix. However I have not come by a fix. I'm hoping someone can Help!
http://jsfiddle.net/kevkin/Aghmc/